# How to create a file with a specific size with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesize

Doing several tests of files validation, I need a file with more than 250MB, but I don't want to store it in the repo.

I'm trying to create a file with NodeJs in time execution with several functions I've found, but they don't work for me.

> This one creates the file, but it doesn't have the size I'm passing.
> Files have just 1 byte.

```
createFile(filePath, size) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    try {
                        const fd = fs.openSync(`${filePath}`, 'w');
                        //fs.writeSync(fd, 'ok', Math.max(0, size - 2));
                        fs.writeSync(fd, Buffer.alloc(1, 'ok', 'base64'), 0, 1,
                            //Math.max(0, size - 1)
                            size - 1
                        );
                        fs.closeSync(fd);
                        resolve(true);
                    } catch (error) {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                }, 0);
            });
        }
```

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: `Buffer.alloc(1...)` may be the issue

Comment: If I use the commented lines instead of that one, it doesn't work either

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you ran your program.  Please describe in detail the expected results vs actual results and the exact text of any error messages you may have encountered.

Comment: I think `Files have just 1 byte` explains the erroneous result @Wyck

Answer (score 0):

> `Buffer.alloc(1...)` may be the issue

When I said that, I meant that Buffer.alloc(someNumber) would be the length of your buffer, which is why the length of the file written to ended up as `1`

I kept your return promise logic in the `createFile` function below

```js
createFile(filePath, size) {
  return new Promise((work,fail)=>{
    fs.writeFile(filePath, Buffer.alloc(size), err=>err?fail(err):work())
    //fs.writeFile(desiredPath, desiredSize, (reject if error and resolve if none))
  })
}
```

Comment: I don't like `r` and `j` for `resolve` and `reject`.

Comment: are `work` and `fail` better names? @Wyck